# LocalStorage a un carrito de compras con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en mi página web la cual incluye un e-commerce. Al carrito le falta mucho trabajo todavía, ya que estoy recién arrancando. Quiero conseguir que cuando se cierre la página el contenido del carrito se almacene en el localStorage de los usuarios, y cuando vuelvan a abrir la página la información siga presente. Estuve probando con varios métodos pero todos fallaron...

Les dejo el código a ver si alguno me puede decir por dónde tengo que encarar.

```
let productos = [
{
    id: 1,
    nombre: "KIMONO VENUM",
    precio: 20000,
    imagen: "../multimedia/kimono.png",
    deporte: "grappling",
},
{
    id: 2,
    nombre: "RUSHGUARD",
    precio: 15000,
    imagen: "../multimedia/rushguard.png",
    deporte: "grappling",
},
{
    id: 3,
    nombre: "GUANTES MMA",
    precio: 8000,
    imagen: "../multimedia/guantesmma.png",
    deporte: "striking",
},
{
    id: 4,
    nombre: "GUANTES BOXEO",
    precio: 10000,
    imagen: "../multimedia/guantesboxeo.png",
    deporte: "striking",
},
{
    id: 5,
    nombre: "BOLSA DE BOXEO",
    precio: 13000,
    imagen: "../multimedia/bolsaboxeo.png",
    deporte: "striking",
},
{
    id: 6,
    nombre: "PROTECTOR BUCAL",
    precio: 4000,
    imagen: "../multimedia/protectorbucal.png",
    deporte: "striking",
},
{
    id: 7,
    nombre: "TIBIALES MMA",
    precio: 6000,
    imagen: "../multimedia/tibiales.png",
    deporte: "striking",
},
{
    id: 8,
    nombre: "CASCO SPARRING",
    precio: 7000,
    imagen: "../multimedia/casco.png",
    deporte: "striking",
},
];

//PRUEBA AGREGAR MI STOCK A LOCALSTORAGE CON FOREACH....


/* localStorage.setItem("productos", JSON.stringify([productos])) 
const mistock = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productos"))

console.log(mistock) */


const crearCards = () => {
    let contenedor = document.getElementById("container")
    productos.forEach((producto, indice) => {
        let card = document.createElement("div")
        card.classList.add("col-xl-3", "col-lg-3", "col-md-6", "col-sm-6")
        card.innerHTML = `<div class="glasses_box">
        <figure><img src="${producto.imagen}" alt="esta es una foto de ${producto.nombre}"/></figure>
        <h3><span class="blu">$</span>${producto.precio}</h3>
        <p>${producto.nombre}</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary boton-comprar" onClick = "agregarAlCarrito (${indice})">COMPRAR</button>
     </div>`

        contenedor.appendChild(card)
    })
}

crearCards();

let cart = [];
let modalCarrito = document.getElementById("cart")


const agregarAlCarrito = (indice) => {
    const indiceEncontradoCarrito = cart.findIndex((elemento) => {
        return elemento.id === productos[indice].id
    })
    if (indiceEncontradoCarrito === -1) {
        const productoAgregar = productos[indice]
        productoAgregar.cantidad = 1
        cart.push(productoAgregar)
        dibujarCarrito()
    }else {
        cart[indiceEncontradoCarrito].cantidad += 1
        dibujarCarrito()
    }
};


let total = 0;

const dibujarCarrito = () => {
    modalCarrito.className = "cart";
    modalCarrito.innerHTML = ""     
    if(cart.length > 0) {
        cart.forEach((producto, indice) => {
            total = total + producto.precio * producto.cantidad;
            const carritoContainer = document.createElement("div");
            carritoContainer.className = "producto-carrito"
            carritoContainer.innerHTML = `
            <img class = "car-img" src="${producto.imagen}"/>
            <div class="product-details">
                ${producto.nombre}
            </div>
            <div class="product-details"> Cantidad: ${producto.cantidad}</div>
            <div class="product-details"> Precio: $ ${producto.precio}</div>
            <div class="product-details"> Subtotal: $ ${
                producto.precio * producto.cantidad
            }</div>
            <button class="btn btn-dark" id="remove-product" onClick="removeProduct(${indice})">Eliminar producto</button>
            `;
            modalCarrito.appendChild(carritoContainer);
        })
        const totalContainer = document.createElement("div")
        totalContainer.className = "total-carrito";
        totalContainer.innerHTML = `<div class = "total"> TOTAL $ ${total} </div>
        <button class = "btn btn-dark finalizar" id="finalizar" onClick = "finalizarCompra()"> FINALIZAR COMPRA </button>`
        modalCarrito.appendChild(totalContainer)

        localStorage.setItem("productos", JSON.stringify(cart)) 
    } else {
        modalCarrito.classList.remove("cart")
    }         
}


const removeProduct = (indice) => {
    cart.splice(indice, 1);
    dibujarCarrito();

}
```

> Este es mi proyecto para continuar con mi curso de desarrollador full stack.

Comment: Cómo fallaron esos intentos? Salió algo en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Si, probe con un foreach a mi array de objetos cuando se haga click a comprar y que eso lo pushee al localStorage, no me arrojaba errores en la consola pero no pude conseguir que el carrito quede con la informacion

Comment: que sale cuando descomentas `console.log(mistock)`?

Comment: absolutamente nada, el array se manda a localstorage pero no queda guardado

Answer (score 1):

Para guardar datos en localstorage  es recomendable serializar la data , es decir convertir los objetos en un formato JSON con la finalidad de que esa data se guarde con un formato con la que pueda ser leída posteriormente entonces el ejemplo a continuación guarda el arreglo de datos en formato JSON y luego lo devuelve como JSON y se convierte a un array para poder recorrerlo y acceder a esos datos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <button id="savebtn">Save data</button>
        <button id="getbtn">Get data</button>
    </div>


    <script>
        var savebtn=document.querySelector('#savebtn');
        var getbtn=document.querySelector('#getbtn');
        var container=document.querySelector('#container');
        var productos = [
            {
                id: 1,
                nombre: "KIMONO VENUM",
                precio: 20000,
                imagen: "../multimedia/kimono.png",
                deporte: "grappling",
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                nombre: "RUSHGUARD",
                precio: 15000,
                imagen: "../multimedia/rushguard.png",
                deporte: "grappling",
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                nombre: "GUANTES MMA",
                precio: 8000,
                imagen: "../multimedia/guantesmma.png",
                deporte: "striking",
            },
            {
                id: 4,
                nombre: "GUANTES BOXEO",
                precio: 10000,
                imagen: "../multimedia/guantesboxeo.png",
                deporte: "striking",
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                nombre: "BOLSA DE BOXEO",
                precio: 13000,
                imagen: "../multimedia/bolsaboxeo.png",
                deporte: "striking",
            },
            {
                id: 6,
                nombre: "PROTECTOR BUCAL",
                precio: 4000,
                imagen: "../multimedia/protectorbucal.png",
                deporte: "striking",
            },
            {
                id: 7,
                nombre: "TIBIALES MMA",
                precio: 6000,
                imagen: "../multimedia/tibiales.png",
                deporte: "striking",
            },
            {
                id: 8,
                nombre: "CASCO SPARRING",
                precio: 7000,
                imagen: "../multimedia/casco.png",
                deporte: "striking",
            },
        ];

        //guardar en localstorage
        function save(array) {
            localStorage.setItem('products',array);
        }

        //obtener datos del localstorage
        function get() {
            return localStorage.getItem('products');
        }

        savebtn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            let jsonArray=JSON.stringify(productos);
            save(jsonArray);
            alert('saved!');
        });

        getbtn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            let array=get();
            let html='';
            let convertJsonToArray=JSON.parse(array);

            convertJsonToArray.map((element)=>{
                html=html+`<div>${element.nombre}</div>`;
            });

            container.innerHTML=html;
        });
        
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: tremendo richard, voy a intentar aplicarlo a mi codigo a ver si puedo conseguir que funcione, te mando un saludo y muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

el problema que veo es que al iniciar envías los datos de tu stock al localStorage con la ley productos
Luego en la función dibujarCarrito usas la misma key
Envías los valores del carrito al localStorage pero al refrescar se sobreescriben, cambia el nombre de alguno
Revisa el localStorage en la vista de desarrollador, cuando vacías el carrito no se borra el último artículo agregado